# LV2 plugins appear only when I am root

Tags: 14.04, permissions, plugins, ardour

I can only see (and use) lv2 plugins when I log in as root. I have tried placing them in the following folders:

```
$home/.lv2
/usr/lib/lv2
/usr/local/lib/lv2
```

When I run `lv2ls` I see nothing. When I run `sudo lv2ls` all the plugins appear. Same thing happens when I run ardour as root.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Comment: The directories you installed them to, or the plug-in directories or files themselves, are only readable by root. Check the permissions of the files, and fix them to be readable by all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had not set the environment variable `LV2_PATH` to point to the plugins folder. To my understanding `lv2ls` and ardour search for plugins in the path set by the variable.

As soon as I set `LV2_PATH` the issue was fixed.